# Installed Ubuntu, still get booted to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I installed Windows 10 on my ASUS laptop, then did the same with Ubuntu. Everything seemed fine, I was at the last screen telling me to restart. That I did, but it simply booted me to Windows 10 with no option to choose OS.

Things that may help:

- My laptop uses FreeDOS, I have no option to choose which OS to boot there (only which "container" to use, like hard drive, USB, DVD disk).
- I have turned fast startup off for my Windows.
- I had 4 partitions before Ubuntu (FreeDOS, Windows, Windows Restore, MyFiles), so I changed the 4th one into an extended partition and made the 5th one during the Ubuntu setup from the unallocated space there.
- I opted out of making a swap partition.
- I have browsed through many topics with similar problems, but nothing really worked.

EDIT: To add on the UEFI, when I'm at FreeDOS or the boot window after pressing Esc when the Asus logo shows up, I don't get to choose an OS. I get a screen with:

Please select boot device:
  P1: Slimtype DVD A DA8... (my DVD)
  P0: TOSHIBA MQ... (my HDD)
  KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP (my USB stick with Ubuntu)
  UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP, Partition 1" (my USB stick, no idea why it goes here again)

EDIT: Here's Boot-Info pastebin:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25934005/

Comment: UEFI BIOS looks at the OS of the drive. if you look at the boot menu in BIOS does it show the Ubuntu partition as a choice?

Comment: press `ESC` key when the manufacturer logo(asus) appears, it's really fast, you'll enter the boot manager, then with the arroww keys select the OS you want to boot.

Comment: It doesn't let me to choose OS. Upon hitting Esc on booting up, I get a screen with:  
"Please select boot device:  
  
1. P1: Slimtype DVD A DA8... (my DVD)  
2. P0: TOSHIBA MQ... (my HDD)  
3. KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP (my USB stick with Ubuntu)  
4. UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0PMAP, Partition 1" (my USB stick, no idea why it goes here again).

Comment: Need to see how you installed UEFI or BIOS. May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred Updated the main post with pastebin.

Comment: You have a BIOS/MBR type install. And Windows boot loader in MBR. Windows does not offer to boot anything other than Windows. You installed grub to same partition as install, but BIOS will never see that. Best to install grub to MBR as it can offer to boot Windows. But with Windows 10 make the repair/recovery drive. If Windows has issues or updates and turns fast start up back on, then grub will not boot Windows & you have to temporarily reinstall the Windows boot loader to MBR with Boot-Repair. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: @oldfred Thanks a lot, but guess I'll give Ubuntu a pass. I use Windows primarily, just needed Ubuntu for few projects, but LiveUSB will have to do. I don't want to risk later along the line having problems booting up Windows.

Comment: I do not recommend it, but some primarily Windows users use EasyBCD. It uses the very old grub4DOS to chainload to a grub install in a partition boot sector (PBR). But grub2 does not easily fit in a PBR and has to convert to blocklists which are not as reliable. So you could boot Windows then Ubuntu but may need to repair grub using Ubuntu live installer on occasion.